# Anet A8 keeps failing prints that it used to be able to complete and new ones

Tags: extruder, anet-a8

The most recognizable problem with my 3D printer is that the extruder stepper keeps clicking. As you can see in these 2 pictures it fails to extrude out plastic in time when doing retractions and when not doing retractions.

[image: Close-up photo of the base of a printed model with printing errors]

[image: Photo of a stopped print with printing errors and the same model printed properly]

I've tried releveling the bed several times, higher and lower printing temperatures, cleaning the nozzle serval times, adjusting print speed, and using brand new PLA filament several times.

So far I have narrowed down the problem to the extruder or the extruder stepper or the software that's interpreting the G-code on the 3D printer. In the pictures above there is the exact same print with the exact same G-code one printed before the printer started messing up and now.

My 3D printer is the Anet A8.

I have no idea what the problem is any ideas?

[image: Photo of Anet A8 3D printer]

[image: Photo of extruder on 3D printer]

[image: Photo of the hotend assembly on the 3D printer]

Comment: Possibly related: [Anet A8 extruder is clicking and not extruding](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4562/anet-a8-extruder-is-clicking-and-not-extruding)

Comment: Is your room temperature and humidity in the room changing with the seasons?

Comment: The room temperature only changes by a few degrees different seasons, on average it’s 70 Degrees Fahrenheit. The humidity rarely changes at all, except a few times a year during monsoon season.